# O6G vs 6G graphics card from same brand

Tags: graphics-cards, pc, cooling

I'm looking at two graphics card models from Asus:

1. DUAL-RTX2060-O6G-EVO
2. DUAL-RTX2060-6G-EVO

As you can see, both are RTX 2060 graphics cards. I compared their official specifications and they have exactly same tech specs except following:

**O6G**
[image]

**6G**
[image]

So, I believe the only difference in both is the clock speeds in Boost and Gaming modes. **O6G** seems better (if more == better).

The price difference is not huge but **O6G** is little more expensive.

Apart from that, my main doubts in choosing one of them are:

1. I will use a stock ryzen coolor (and a low budget B550M motherboard) with my Ryzen 5 5600 CPU. So I feel if I buy **O6G**, it will give better performance while doing work/gaming but at the cost of more heat generation
2. I personally feel like OC graphic cards generally generate more heat and *performance boost is not that significant*. So a default clock GPU would be better if heat is a factor.
3. Even if I buy the **O6G** model, I will tend to use it a default base clock to ensure a longer life of the card and less heat. I would disable the OC feature. *But I'm not sure if it is officially provided by a GPU brand in their OC GPUs or not.* If there's a feature/option provided by GPU brand (Asus in this case) to disable OC mode, I would probably buy any of the models. For example, I would buy **O6G** if it were cheaper. It won't make a difference to me. I've read that *Afterburner* software allows you to change clocks and power but I don't want to use any third party software. I'm not comfortable with tweaking settings and I fear I'll mess up the hardware.
4. If the difference is not just the clock speeds and minor gaming/working improvements as discussed above, e.g. some other useful feature/function/benefit which *O6G* has and *6G* doesn't have, I don't want to be limited to them. I will probably go for *O6G*.

I've also read here and there that factor OC cards can have little less life as compared to default ones.

**So given all my doubts, which would you recommend? Would you still recommend O6G?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The O6G is probably better binned silicon by Asus which is tested to be more stable at higher boost clocks. But looking at all your concerns it looks like the 6G is a better fit for your needs, since the difference might not be that great for the money and you want to keep it at stock speeds without tweaking. IMO just go for the 6G, at the very worst, if you wish, you could probably OC it to match the 06G if you ever get comfortable with Ocing. Thats why the 06G was created, for folks who dont want to OC their GPU's

Answer (score 2):

OC cards are generally well tested and have better sillicon than the non OC cards (same heat output, better performance, although not by much), so that mostly eliminates doubt 1 and 2. For doubt 3, use Afterburner (Windows, closed source) or GreenWithEnvy (Linux and FOSS) to undervolt your card. This software cannot break your GPU permenantly and if you only undervolt lightly (-10 mV), nothing else than heat output should change. The other features are not availible on the O6G, since they are just both 2060s. If the budget allows it, get the O6G